# Redux + typescript: how to implement `injectReducer`?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm working on a typescript react app using redux to manage state.

To dynamically add reducers, redux suggested to implement a [`injectReducer` function](https://redux.js.org/usage/code-splitting#defining-an-injectreducer-function).

I've done that in a Javascript project, but I couldnot figure how to do this with typescript.

Any advice would be very helpful!

What I've tried so far:

```js
export interface AppStore extends EnhancedStore<{}> {
  injectedReducers?: any;
}

const store: AppStore = configureStore({
  reducer: createReducer(),
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
});

store.injectedReducers = {};

export const injectReducer = (key: string, reducer: Reducer<object>) => {
  if (store.injectedReducers[key]) {
    return;
  }
  store.injectedReducers[key] = reducer;
  
  store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.injectedReducers));
  return store;
};

export default function createReducer(injectedReducers?: any) {
  return combineReducers({
    global: globalReducer,
    ...injectedReducers,
  });
}
```

And here is the error message from `createReducer(store.injectedReducers!)`:

```
Argument of type 'Reducer<CombinedState<{ [x: string]: unknown; }>, never>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<{}, AnyAction>'.
  Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
    Type 'AnyAction' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: First - please don't use `any`.
Next, `createReducer` function gets two parameters, initial `state` and `reducer`.

Please, check [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer)

Answer (score 2):

The work around I'm using is to export another function from my store file that will inject reducers into my store.

```
import selectedContextSlice from "./selectedContextSlice";
import { combineReducers, configureStore, Reducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { userProfileSlice } from "./userProfileSlice";
import { viewSlice } from "./viewSlice";
import authClientsSlice from "./authClientsSlice";

const containerReducers = {
  authClients: authClientsSlice.reducer,
  selectedContext: selectedContextSlice.reducer,
  userProfile: userProfileSlice.reducer,
  view: viewSlice.reducer
};

const store = configureStore({ reducer: containerReducers });

function registerReducers(newReducers: Reducer) {
  store.replaceReducer(
    combineReducers({ ...containerReducers, ...newReducers })
  );
}

export default store;
export { registerReducers as injectReducers };
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Comment: How would you add new reducers to the already existing ones in the store? In your example you have the existing ones in the containerReducers but if I would call the injectReducers multiple times, it would always create the store from scratch instead of adding to it. Is this possible too?